# How to get access to an internal bitmap of a window?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I am concerned after reading [an article about how to render to a device context with AGG library](http://blog.miranda.or.at/2010/09/rendering-to-a-device-context-with-agg-antigrain).

The article reads:

> A device context is not a real render target, it is just a data
>   structure holding information about a render target. When you use a
>   GDI function to render to a DC, the function will only use the DC to
>   obtain information how and where it has to set its pixels. The actual
>   render target is a in-memory bitmap which is selected into the device
>   context.

The AGG library uses a bitmap buffer as a render target. I need to render graphics to the window. The most obvious way is to create a memory bitmap and BitBlt it to the window DC.

But is there a better way? Is it possible to get access to the internal bitmap of a window to render to it?

Comment: If you are rendering from your paint cycle, the `BeginPaint` function gives you a DC to the window. If you are rendering from outside your paint cycle (not recommended), `GetDC` will give you a DC for the window. Note that doing so bypasses whatever AGG does, so you need to check with AGG that what you're doing is okay with them.

Comment: It's not clear whether you áre using the AGG library. Do you, or is this a general question about how to draw efficiently on a DC?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not select a bitmap into the DC by yourself, then you can obtain the current selected bitmap in that DC with `GetCurrentObject(DC, OBJ_BITMAP)`. If the result is NULL, then you have to create and select a bitmap yourself first.

Use that bitmap handle in the AGG Attach routine.